# Filtering with exists in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, exists

I'm running the following query in bigQuery and I don't have the expected output. Isn't that only the row with Alpha should be returned?

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT(NULL AS a, '' AS b),
  (1, 'Alpha'),
  (2, 'Bravo'),
  (3, 'Charlie'),
  (4, 'Delta')
])
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT(NULL AS a, '' AS b),
  (1, 'Alpha')
]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below instead

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT(NULL AS a, '' AS b),
  (1, 'Alpha'),
  (2, 'Bravo'),
  (3, 'Charlie'),
  (4, 'Delta')
])
WHERE (a,b) in UNNEST([
  STRUCT(NULL AS a, '' AS b),
  (1, 'Alpha')
])
```

with output

[image]

Comment: That's the one I'm using but I'm wondering why the EXISTS option is not working

Comment: because expression under exists is ALWAY true :o) no matter what row in main set is evaluated!

Comment: so when for example the row Bravo is compared to the row Alpha in the exists statement, it returns true? and not filtering is executed?

Comment: yes, as I said, no matter which row is evaluated  - expression with the EXISTS always returns two rows, meaning that whole EXISTS ends up being true - always!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `WHERE` clause in your `EXISTS` subquery, that's why it  always return rows and is evaluated to `true`.

Try this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT(NULL AS a, '' AS b),
  (1, 'Alpha'),
  (2, 'Bravo'),
  (3, 'Charlie'),
  (4, 'Delta')
]) t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST([
        STRUCT(NULL AS a, '' AS b),
              (1, 'Alpha')
       ]) t2
    WHERE t1.a = t2.a -- add this condition
)
```